# A is not known to exist in the repository and is not part of the commit, yet its child B is part of commit

Tags: svn, commit, changelist

Unable to commit a directory as part of changelist.

If I do

```
svn commit --changelist MYCHANGELIST -m "MYMESSAGE"
```

I get

'A' is not known to exist in the repository and is not part of the commit, yet its child 'A/myfile.cpp' is part of the commit

If I am trying to add directory to a commit

svn changelist MYCHANGELIST A

I get

```
Skipped 'A'
```

So I have vicious circle.

How to overcome?

---

The same may happen with no any changelists... What to do in the situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can't commit to the repo any object, which isn't a part of tree, thus - all parents of changelist's members must be in repository *or* committed with changelist, obviously.

If you got "skipped ..." message on commit, I suppose (can't test and too lazy to build testpad) you have A in ignore-list, check it with `svn st --no-ignore`. Ignored objects can't be committed to the repo **by design and purpose**, but you can force add ignored objects to repo and these addition will be stored in repo and used later

Read about global [`--parents`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.parents) option, use it in `svn ci` or, maybe, in `svn add` before commit